# Magento 2 : Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2, category, form-key

I get this error when I try to save a category,

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

I tried the following solutions from various other posts

- Increase php_value max_input_vars 75000
- Try to clear the cache from var/cache directory.
- Then clear browser cache. Especially clear or delete cookies.

But no success for me, what other reasons could cause this issue?

Comment: Where are you getting this message?

Comment: When trying to save a category in Catalog > Categories

Comment: does the form key exist in your html?

Comment: yes it is available on the url

Comment: Hi @nuwaus, your question content and the tag you have mentioned do not match. Kindly make necessary changes in your question and try to clarify a bit more so that someone can help easily.

Comment: @nuwaus, from the Session.php file path, it seems Magento 1.x but you have mentioned Magento2 in the tags.

Comment: You are usingm m1 or m2?

Comment: It is magento 2

Comment: please check this [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208788/magento-2-2-2-on-product-save-i-get-error-invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the) Thanks